# Format stack trace in html in python

Tags: python, html, formatting, python-2.x

The project I'm currently working on runs tests for hardware on a server. These tests write to log files and a report file (summary of test run). I now am adding functionality to also write a report file in html form. The goal is to make the html version look very similar to the .txt report file. This also means formatting stacktraces.

The reason for the html report is that I can create links to certain files or images, if say a test went wrong.

Edit:
function where I write to file:

```py
def end_run(self, current_run, total_runs, errors, statistics):
#              this breakline correctly writes to file
        self.file.write("<br>")
#              this breakline correctly writes to file
        self.file.write(self.width * "=" + "<br>")
        for e in errors:
#              this breakline correctly writes to file
            exception = "Exception #%d: (%s) %s<br>&ensp; Stacktrace: " % (e.seq_nr,
                                                                          e.exception.__class__.__name__,
                                                                           str(e.exception)) 
            # HERE I FORMAT
            exception += r" ".join(self.format_stacktrace(traceback.format_list(e.traceback)))
#           SHOWS <br> tags
            print exception
            # THIS WRITE DOES NOT WRITE <br> tag
            self.file.write(exception)
            if e.occurances > 1:
#              this breakline correctly writes to file
                self.file.write(" (occured %d times)<br>" % (e.occurances))
            else:
#              this breakline correctly writes to file
                self.file.write("<br>")

            if len(e.parameter_set) > 0:
#              this breakline correctly writes to file
                self.file.write("Active parameter set:<br>")
                for k, v in e.parameter_set.items():
#              this breakline correctly writes to file
                    self.file.write("  %-20s: %s<br>" % (str(k), str(v)))
            self.file.write("Traceback:<br>")
            traceback.print_list(e.traceback, file=self.file)
#              this breakline correctly writes to file
            self.file.write(self.width * "-" + "<br>")
        self.file.write(self.html_end)
        # flush after printing the exception tracebacks so the file will be updated
        self.file.flush()
```

The format function:

```py
    def format_stacktrace(self, stacktrace):
        """
        formats stack trace for html.
        @param stacktrace: stacktrace already formatted by traceback.format_list(stacktrace)
        """ 
        return map(lambda x: x.replace("\n", "<br>"), stacktrace)
```

the print statement outputs this:

`'  File "../common/ip/pyart/testrunner.py", line 259, in _run_function<br />    function(**parameter_set)<br />'`

`'  File "../common/ip/pyart/testrunner.py", line 96, in __call__<br />    return getattr(self._function.im_self, self._function.func_name)(**self._parameter_set)<br />'`

`'  File "testcases/art/case_270_video_dvi_edid.py", line 87, in test_000_set_and_clear_edid_resolution<br />    self.fail("test")<br />'`

Which seems to be correct, but some `<br />` are missing in the final html file.

```html
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf_8">
            <title>Basic Report</title>
            <meta name="author" content="Technolution">
        </head>
        
        <body style="font-family: courier">Starting suite 'SigmaXG Testcases'<br>&emsp;&emsp;Starting case 'EDID test case'<br>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;Running test 'set and clear EDID to video source for 1920x1080p60.0'................................................... <a href="exception_log_1.txt">FAIL (#1)</a><br>&emsp;&emsp;Ending case (FAIL: 1 tests failed)<br>Ending suite (FAIL: 1 test cases failed)<br><br>================================================================================================================================================================<br>Exception #1: (PyARTTestFailException) test<br>&ensp; 

<!-- relevant part --> Stacktrace:   File "../common/ip/pyart/testrunner.py", line 259, in _run_function
    function(**parameter_set)
   File "../common/ip/pyart/testrunner.py", line 96, in __call__
    return getattr(self._function.im_self, self._function.func_name)(**self._parameter_set)
   File "testcases/art/case_270_video_dvi_edid.py", line 87, in test_000_set_and_clear_edid_resolution
    self.fail("test")
<br>Active parameter set:<br>  input_mode          : 1920x1080p60.0<br>Traceback:<br>  File "../common/ip/pyart/testrunner.py", line 259, in _run_function
    function(**parameter_set)
  File "../common/ip/pyart/testrunner.py", line 96, in __call__
    return getattr(self._function.im_self, self._function.func_name)(**self._parameter_set)
  File "testcases/art/case_270_video_dvi_edid.py", line 87, in test_000_set_and_clear_edid_resolution
    self.fail("test")
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br></body></html>
```

For example the `<br />` tag between `function(**parameter_set)` and `File ...` shows in print output but not in resulting html file.
What am I missing here?

Comment: First of all, is there a reason in particular that you’re using python 2.*?

Comment: @anonjnr This project (reporting on test runs) was made in python2.x quite some time ago. I don't really have the authority to change this unfortunately...

Comment: Have you checked if probably \r is also used for line breaks?

Comment: @anonjnr Clearly not because why would there be `<br>` tags in the string after replace? ....